# Java Logging & Unix Nohup problem

Tags: java, unix, logging, log4j, nohup

I have created a small program which logs text data to a file on some action. I am accessing the remote system where the program is deployed by Putty. I have run the program using nohup so that it keeps running even if i shut down my shell. Till the time i am logged into the shell it continues to log the data. However, as soon as i exit my shell it stops writing to the log file. My program still continues to run just that it doesn't write to the log file. 
I am using Java 1.6 + slf4j+log4j for logging. The OS is Ubuntu.

Would appreciate some help.

**EDIT:**
my log4j.properties

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG

log4j.appender.AdminFileAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.AdminFileAppender.File=pdmLogs.log
log4j.appender.AdminFileAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.AdminFileAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} -- %p %t %c - %m%n

log4j.appender.ReportFileAppender=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.ReportFileAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.ReportFileAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} -- %p %t %c - %m%n

log4j.logger.com.xxx.xxx.yyy=ReportFileAppender,AdminFileAppender
log4j.logger.com.xxx.xxx.zzz=ReportFileAppender,AdminFileAppender
```

The command which I am running is:

```
nohup java -cp jarfile.jar com.xxx.xxx.yyy.Main &
```

Comment: Did you run it as `nohup java -cp ... myMainClass &` ? (Note the `&`)

Comment: yes I ran it in the background

Comment: Is your log4j configured with a `console appender` as well? If yes - have you tried to turn it off an leave just the `file appender`?

Comment: Yes a console Appender is there. I shall turn it off and see

Comment: Maybe I am doing Something wrong but when i turn off the Console Appender no logs are created. I am not using ConsoleAppender for anything though

Comment: Post your `log4j.xml`/`log4j.properties` - it might help.

And the exact command you are running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your configuration to:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, AdminFileAppender
...
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you run the program? After running the program, do you see it among the list of process running by doing `ps -ef | grep <process-id>` Just to make sure, your program doesn't block at any time waiting for input? Also, check on the exit value of your process.

Comment: yes i see the program running. It's basically a TCP Server which accepts requests from clients and logs the data sent to it by clients. So even when shutting down the shell I am still able to connect to the TCP Server and send data.